# How to resolve Error: Could not find or load main class in SpringBoot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, java-8, spring-tools-4

I have one SpringBoot application with maven setup. When I run maven clean, install, generate-sources , build succeed but when I run it as spring boot application, it gives error Error: Could not find or load main class

For trial I created simple java hello world project in the same workspace which is working fine. So this issue is not related with classpath variables or JDK.

Can you tell me what wrong I might be doing in SpringBoot application?

Comment: Can you specify the folder structure. Your pom.xml and Main class. It would be useful in finding the issue.

Comment: also can you try to create a new Spring Boot maven project using the Spring Starter Wizard and run that as a Spring Boot application to see if that works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try giving the main class in the POM file, as shown below.

[ if main class is 'com.dev.webapp.Application' ]

```
<properties>
    <start-class>com.dev.webapp.Application</start-class>
</properties>
```